# Visual Studio C++ Header and CPP linking errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include, header-files

I have a project set up like this:

```
Header (.h) files
 ________________                 _________ 
| Main Big Class |---------------| ModuleB |
| - libraries    |   _________   | -SubMod |    
|________________|--| ModuleA |  |_________|
                    | -SubMod |       |
                    |_________|   ____|____
                         |       | SubModB |
                     ____|____   |_________|
                    | SubModA |
                    |_________|

All Code (.cpp) files have #include "Main Big Class.h"
```

So on ModuleA's submodules they don't have any includes in their headers, and they only have the *#include "Main.h"* on their .cpp files, where I have #includes for strings, vectors, and everything else I use in the project.
On the ModuleA I have the include for all it's submodules, and I am able to use vector and strings in any submodule from ModuleA..

Now that I'm moving to ModuleB, I added a new submodule and did it the same as before, ModuleB has:

```
#include "SubModuleB1.h"
#include "SubModuleB2.h"
```

But when I try to compile, Visual Studio shows errors on the lines where I have strings and vectors in these submodules from B.

Sometimes commenting the lines, compiling, then uncommenting them might compile, but I have to do this line by line and a single error means it won't compile unless I comment them all again.

I tried to Clean and Rebuild already, didn't work, and I don't know why this happens.

Why does this happens and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** The errors are 3 per line:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: did you `using namespace std;` in your code?

Comment: Yes, it's in the Main header file. All other submodules and module A compile fine with strings and vectors, it's just this new created submodule from B that doesn't. I remember this happened when I was creating A submodules as well, but after a while (and builds) it went away, but I don't know why it did.

Answer (score 0):

In your cpp files , add the following

```
   using namespace std;
```

For error C4430, I think you forget `void` or `int` when your define your function, like

```
    void myfunction (...)
    {
        //
    }
```

but in your code you only have

```
    myfunction()
    {
        //
     }
```

Comment: The 3 errors appear on the line where I have the line "string testString;". As soon as I comment this line, everything else compiles fine.

Comment: what are the lines before and after `string testString;`?  What does the line with the error message look like?

Comment: It's a simple class with just the constructor, and "private: string testString;". There's just that in the error line that the compiles points to. It's always these 3 errors for the same line, so if I have 3 strings, I get 9 errors, etc.

Comment: Weird, why the compiler complains about `<`? there is no `<` in line `string testString;`, right? Can you just post some sample code?